# Problema con LAST_INSERT_ID

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Estoy intentando obtener el siguiente número de una columna llamada `TARIMA`, el problema es que no está `autoincremento` ya que es aparte de `ID` general `AI`, intente utilizar `lastinsertid` para obtener el siguiente `int` de la tabla pero no me devuelve nada.

```
$rs = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT MAX(tarima) FROM tarima_detalles");
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs)) {
        $codigo = trim($row[0]);

         if(mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tarima_detalles (TARIMA, SEPARACION, Cajas, Peso,calidad) VALUES ('$codigo','$separacion','$cajas','$peso','$calidad')")){
              echo(mysqli_insert_id($con));
          }else{
               echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
          }
          mysqli_close($con);
        }else{
            echo "ERROR";
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo me repite datos, excepto si estaba vacía no inserta nada.:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que la función `Max()` te devuelve el resultado más alto de una lista, es decir

Teniendo los números: `2, 1, 6, 7`

Al usar `Max(): 7`

En tú caso cuando haces el `Max -> MAX(tarima)` tu número más alto de la lista es el `1`, por lo tanto, el resultado de `Max()` es `1`.

Puedes usar el `MAX(tarima)` pero antes de insertar, le sumas `+ 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtenerlo directamente con esta consulta:

```
SELECT tarima + 1 AS tarima_nueva
FROM tarima_detalles 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Lo que hace es buscar el registro con mayor `id` (que al ser autoincremental siempre sería el más reciente), y sumarle 1 a su valor `tarima`.
Luego, el valor lo obtendrías en `$row['tarima_nueva']`.